# Tomcat6 Manager Webapp returns a 404

Tags: 10.10, configuration, apache2, tomcat6

http://localhost:8080/manager/html gives a 404 error on apt-get install of tomcat6 (6.0.28 on JVM 1.6.0_20-b20 on 2.6.35-27-generic amd64).

http://localhost:8080/host-manager/html works. Lists one Host name, localhost.

Installed tomcat6-admin with apt-get.

```
ls dpkg -l | grep -i tomcat6-admin
```

`ii  tomcat6-admin                        6.0.28-2ubuntu1.1                                 Servlet and JSP engine -- admin web applications`

```
$ cat /usr/share/tomcat6/conf/tomcat-users.xml

<tomcat-users>
<role rolename="admin"/>
<role rolename="manager" />
<user username="tomcatuser" password="Password1" roles="admin,manager"/>
</tomcat-users>

cat /usr/share/tomcat6/conf/Catalina/localhost/manager.xml

<Context path="/manager" 
    docBase="/usr/share/tomcat6-admin/manager" 
    antiResourceLocking="false" privileged="true" />
<role name="manager" />
<user name="manager" password="Password1" roles="manager" />
<user name="tomcatuser" password="Password1" roles="manager" />
```

Those two files are the only documentation I've seen on how to setup the Manager webapp, and they seem to be compliant with the requirements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pursing the error log message from `catalina.out`, finally realized that I got confused when copy-pasting and put the `<role>` and `<user>` tags in both `tomcat-users.xml` and `manager.xml`. Those tags can only go in `tomcat-users.xml`. Once the tags were removed from `manager.xml`, the Manager began working.

To restate, the only contents of `manager.xml` are

```
<Context path="/manager"
docBase="/usr/share/tomcat6-admin/manager"
antiResourceLocking="false" privileged="true" />
```

Would be nice to

1. Have better error message in the parser
2. Require the manager.xml to be well-formed
3. not have the Manager serve a 404 error when a deployment fails.